# What is an ungrounded extension cord? Is it dangerous?

Tags: grounding

The definition of a grounded extension cord from [this](https://techpenny.com/extension-cords-grounded/) website is:

> If you have a three-pronged extension cord, it is grounded.

Why is that so? What do we mean by "grounded" in this case?

My concern comes from the fact that I was accused of using a dangerous extension cord because it is "ungrounded."

The extension cord is the one in the picture.

[image]

I do not understand where the dangerous aspect is since all conductor wires are insulated.

Comment: Can you show another picture with both ends of the cord facing the camera? Many of the answers are assuming the female end has 3 pins because the male end clearly has three pins (which isn’t a bad assumption). But posting a pic with those details would be better than assuming.

Comment: Yes also the female end has 3 pins. What does it change if it is was 2 ? @SteKulov

Comment: I hate when I click on a picture to see a larger version and it's... the same.

Comment: It's ok (in many countries) to have ungrounded extension cords. I have some and they're safe to use because they only have two pins and will not accept a device that needs ground. What is not ok is to have an ungrounded extension cord that has a connector that fits a grounded plug, since it's advertising that it provides that ground but not actually connecting it.

Comment: thanks @user1850479.

Comment: Yes.  Exactly what @user1850479 said.  If the female had only two pins, then the number of wires matches anything that can fit into the female end.  At least in the USA, female 2-pin ports have extra plastic to block something with a 3rd pin from connecting.  Also in the USA, this extension cord of yours is equivalent to [using a grounding adapter](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006IBFB) in a 2-pin outlet without connecting the green metal tab to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the third prong is to provide a "protective earth", or a direct connection to a safe voltage through its own wire that is not used for delivering power.

When designing a safe device, it's necessary to ensure that a failure (e.g. a broken wire) cannot lead to an electric shock. The IEC defines [a number of techniques for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes), one of which is Class I:

> the casing and other conductive parts are also connected with a low-resistant earth conductor

If there is a failure inside the device, and a broken wire touches the outside case, the grounding connection will prevent the outside case from having a dangerous voltage.

Instead, the dangerous current will flow to protective earth through the grounding prong of the cable, and that current may cause a circuit breaker to shut off the supply if the current is large enough. This protects you - the case does not develop a dangerous voltage.

However, this assumes that the device is actually connected to protective earth - if that connection is absent, then the device is now dangerous. If a wire breaks and touches the outer case, the outer case is now live and able to cause an electric shock to anybody that touches it.

Your extension cord does have three prongs, but it only has two wires. It cannot carry both power and protective earth to the device plugged into it. If the device becomes faulty in a dangerous way, the primary safety mechanism of earthing is no longer able to keep you safe.

Beyond that, the wires look thin. This cable ought to be discarded or destroyed for safety.

Comment: Ok thank you very much @nanofarad, that is the point I wanted to know. So it is dangerous only in cases in which for example the wire is broken and I touch the conductive wire ?

Comment: @HelpNeederStudent I would not use the phrase "only" here. It's simply dangerous, even if it's not going to *immediately* cause injury/death. Better to think of it as: "it's one failure/wire break away from shocking/electrocuting someone". You don't know when a wire might break *inside* a device, and you won't see it. With this extension cord, that device will immediately injure or kill someone as soon as that wire break happens. **Don't risk it.**

Comment: Sorry, however if the wire breaks inside the device, that device is insulating and so it should protect you.... isn't it ?

Comment: @HelpNeederStudent:  Some devices are insulated, some aren't.  If your extension cable doesn't have the ground, and someone plugs in a device that isn't double insulated, and that device has fault, then you could die.  It depends on many things going wrong.  That's why safety requires you to do many things right to prevent the wrongs from killing you.

Comment: Ah ok now I better understand.

Answer (score 2):

An extension cable with three pins normally has three wires:  hot, neutral, and ground.  They will be connected so that all three wires in the plug of the extension cable are connected to the same parts of the socket so that plugging an appliance into the extension cord is the same as pluggin the extension cord into the outlet.

The pictured extension cord has three pins but only two wires.  It needs to have three wires to properly connect all three pins in the plug and the socket.

Since your extension cord only has two wires, it cannot be properly wired.  That is dangerous.

Normally, current only flows through the hot and neutral wires.  That's all you need to make an appliance work.

The third wire is for safety.  It is connected to the grounding system of the house. The ground wire of your appliance is also connected to the ground wire through the cable to the ground system of your house.

If something inside the appliance breaks, it could connect the hot wire with the housing (or other metal part) of the appliance - that could kill you.  The housings are, however, connected to the ground wire so that instead of killing you, the circuit breaker in the house trips.

Your extension cable is the worst sort of dangerous.  It has the safety ground in the plug and the socket, but doesn't have them connected because there are only two wires in the cable - it needs three.  It looks safe (grounded plug, grounded socket) but it is dangerous.  That's the worst kind.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. However, at this point, I do not understand the following: why a simple computer charger cable does not need this system of three wires ?

Comment: There's what's called "double insulated" devices.  The housings are built such that nothing inside can put line voltage on the housing.  The housings and all controls are built such that the user cannot touch any metal that might be at line voltage.  Such devices have a marking on them or say "double insulated."

Comment: Just a comment to mention that through an extension cord you can get possible swapping of live and neutral in many cabling systems around the world.

Answer (score 2):

The cord looks self-made.

I hope the cabling used is at least rated for mains voltages and currents, instead of being random speaker wire.

The problem is you have two wires in the cable but the plugs are three pin plugs.

The cord really is dangerous as it allows plugging in devices that require ground for safety and proper operation without providing ground.

Grounded plugs need three wires between them.

Best to get rid of that extension cord and buy one from a shop.